# Exception: Unable to run "adb", check your Android SDK installation and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Tags: flutter, android-studio, adb, flutter-doctor

I have a problem installing flutter as in the picture and have tried various methods on Google but nothing works, can anyone help me fix it? Thank you.

[image]

When I run `adb device -l` it appears like this:

[image]

When I create a project, android studio device can be detected, but when I create a flutter project on android studio device it is not detected:

[image]

[image]

Comment: so, do you have adb.exe located at `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe` ? what happens when you run it? If not, have you tried to call: `flutter config --android-studio-dir <directory>` (and replace <directory> with the installation directory of android studio.

Comment: when I run adb.exe it opens and closes immediately, when i call `flutter config --android-studio-dir <directory>` and run `flutter doctor' previously detected android studio becomes undetectable like this [!] Android Studio
    X android-studio-dir = C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.